# SQL Azure: What will happen if size of my SQL Azure get 5GB?

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I need to know what will happen when a database in SQL Azure exeeds its size. For example I defined a 1GB database and this is going over its size limit. Will it change to a 5GB database?

Comment: Database size can be adjusted in the Azure Portal.

Answer (score 19):

You won't be able to go over 1GB unless you specifically allow for it. You'll actually get an error code when attempting to go beyond 1GB.

To increase max size, execute this T-SQL:
`ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase MODIFY (EDITION='WEB', MAXSIZE=5GB`)

For more info about altering database sizes, see [this blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20140818071643/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/06/16/10026036.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I believe the answer can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee336245.aspx#dcasl
Which means that the database will not automatically grow to 5 GB, but you will receive an error and you have to manually alter your database to change the MAXSIZE of your database

**Update:**
This is the error I received when my Web Edition database reached 1GB:

*TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.*

*Communication link failure*

*The database has reached its size quota. Partition or delete data, drop indexes, or consult the documentation for possible resolutions.*