# Upgrading SQL Azure database size

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I'm currently in the middle of developing an application *loosely* similar to StackOverflow (question / answer based)

Initially, I was using AWS (simple db and s3) for storage, however that posed several problems, and i've opted to go with SQL - With a view to eventually hosting on SQL Azure.

I was just wondering, if i opted for the 1gb database initially, could I increase the size to the 5gb / 10gb databases later on? Or would I have to create a separate new database of this size, and port my data over?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

See my answer on this [other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254630/sql-azure-what-will-happen-if-size-of-my-sql-azure-get-5gb/3256963#3256963). In a nutshell, you modify db size with T-SQL, such as:

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase MODIFY (EDITION='WEB', MAXSIZE=5GB)
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also change the size of the database through the Azure SQL portal. Simply choose the database and go to the scale tab and select the size you want.

Tada

Answer (score 5):

Just wanted to expand on Dave's answer since it is very easy in the management tool:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: ... it is now, but back in 2010, this feature didn't exist

Comment: Actually it did in the Old Portal and Via the Database MAnagement portal as well.

Comment: I got really stressed out when an error appeared in our logs saying our DB is full. Thank God the solution was this simple! We are paying for a 250 GB database, why would it default be set to 10 GB?

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with [SQL Azure Pools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-pool) than you can execute the follow from the `master`

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name
MODIFY (MAXSIZE = x GB)
```

The key difference being the omission of the 'Edition` parameter. There are certain size restrictions though, which can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-resource-limits).