# How to Resize a SQL Azure Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

How do I resize my SQL Azure Web Edition 5 GB database to a 1 GB database? I no longer need the extra capacity and do not want to be billed at the higher rate. I don't see anything in the Management Portal and a quick web search also turned up nothing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254630/sql-azure-what-will-happen-if-size-of-my-sql-azure-get-5gb/3256963#3256963). It should be as simple as running an ALTER DATABASE command:

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase MODIFY (EDITION='WEB', MAXSIZE=1GB)
```

Just keep this in mind: As long as your usage is <= 1GB, you'll be billed at the 1GB rate. Billing is monthly but amortized daily. So you actually don't need to reduce your max size unless you're relying on SQL Azure to prevent you from growing beyond 1GB.

**EDIT**: As of Feb. 2012, there's a new 100MB pricing tier (at $4.99, vs. $9.99 at 1GB). While you can't set MAXSIZE to 100MB, your monthly cost will drop if you stay under 100MB. See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2012/02/14/announcing-reduced-pricing-on-sql-azure-and-new-100mb-database-option.aspx) for more details.