# SQL Azure - Substring Searches?

Tags: sql, search, text, azure

SQL Azure does not support SQL Server's Full Text Search feature.
Does this mean a text field cannot be indexed to handle substring searches?

For example, if I have a table Emails, with a Message column
And I want to find all messages with both the words 'hello' and 'thanks' in them, will the standard index on the message collumn allow me to do this?

```
CREATE TABLE Emails (
    [Id] bigint  NOT NULL,
    [Message] nvarchar({some number})  NOT NULL
);
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX Messages_Emails ON Emails


my query (using entity) would look like
var niceMessageQuery = Context.Emails.Where(e => e.Message.Contains("hello") && e.Message.Contains("thanks"));
```

Is there a better way to setup this query?

Answer (score 1):

As of April 2015 Full-Text Search is available in Azure Sql Database server version V12: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/04/30/full-text-search-is-now-available-for-preview-in-azure-sql-database/.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar at all with azure, but is it possible to use a subquery?  The inner (sub) query find all records that contain "hello" and the outer query uses that inner query as it's dataset to search for "thanks"?