# sending email from sql azure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, triggers, azure-sql-database

Hey all,
just quick question about sql azure. My App is running on windows azure and the database is on sql azure. Everything is working great. However, I would like to send email to a user, as soon as he\she became a member.I don't  want to Use

  - third party service

  - send email from the code.

Is there any way to send email by using a trigger and stored procedure? For example: run trigger after each updated for user table and trigger will run stored procedure. 
Thanks in advance . Matt

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure mail on Azure SQL Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54782922/how-to-configure-mail-on-azure-sql-database)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there is no way to send an email from SQL Azure directly.  You will have to use a web, worker or VM role to actually send email.  In general, sending email from Azure data centers is tricky because spam filters flag Azure IP addresses as unsafe (see https://alinirimie.sys-con.com/node/1404827).  To avoid this problem, you must use a third party SMTP service (we use [Amazon SES](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/)) or your own SMTP server.  If you want to connect to your own SMTP server through a firewall, you can use [Windows Azure Connect](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/virtualnetwork/default.aspx) to establish a secure tunnel from Azure to your local network.

Answer (score 2):

I realize you stated that you do not want to use a 3rd party services, but for others that might be reading this and would be open to this.  Cotega allows you to [send emails directly from SQL Azure](https://cotega.com/docs/send_email_from_sql_azure).

Full disclosure, I work on Cotega.

Answer (score 1):

There is some documentation on hacks you can do here: http://vpolizzi.wordpress.com/2010/09/11/database-mail-on-sql-azure/

However I think using a worker role would be more robust and maintainable.