# SQL Server 2008 to SQL Azure sp_helpuser and sp_send_dbmail

Tags: sql-server-2008, migration, azure-sql-database

I receive the messages that the following sp_helpuser and sp_send_dbmail are not supported on azure.

What is the recommended way to fix this?

Here's where these sp's are used:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[aspnet_Setup_RemoveAllRoleMembers]
    @name   sysname
    AS
    BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #aspnet_RoleMembers
(
    Group_name      sysname,
    Group_id        smallint,
    Users_in_group  sysname,
    User_id         smallint
)

INSERT INTO #aspnet_RoleMembers
EXEC sp_helpuser @name <--here it is

DECLARE @user_id smallint
DECLARE @cmd nvarchar(500)
DECLARE c1 cursor FORWARD_ONLY FOR
    SELECT User_id FROM #aspnet_RoleMembers

OPEN c1

FETCH c1 INTO @user_id
WHILE (@@fetch_status = 0)
BEGIN
    SET @cmd = 'EXEC sp_droprolemember ' + '''' + @name + ''', ''' + USER_NAME(@user_id) + ''''
    EXEC (@cmd)
    FETCH c1 INTO @user_id
END

CLOSE c1
DEALLOCATE c1
END
GO
```

And the other sp:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSendMail]
@To VARCHAR(200),
@Subject VARCHAR(200),
@Body VARCHAR(MAX) = '',
@From VARCHAR(50) = 'info.pt@consultaclick.com',
@format VARCHAR(20) = 'HTML' --HTML
 AS

DECLARE
@profile VARCHAR(50)

select @profile = P.DBMailProfile from tblPaises P INNER JOIN tblParametros PR On P.Codigo = PR.Pais


EXEC MSDB..sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = @profile,
        @recipients =  'someone@somewhere.pt;someon@somehwere.pt',
        --@recipients =  @To,
        --@from_address = @From,
        @subject = @Subject,
        @Body = @Body,
        @body_format = @format
GO
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [sending email from sql azure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132200/sending-email-from-sql-azure)

Comment: it's not duplicate because I ask for sp_helpuser

Comment: Have you had chance to try my suggestions?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem over a year later - did you manage to resolve this in the end?

Answer (score 4):

Yes "sp_helpuser" is not supported in SQL Azure, so if you want to impersonate another user, you can use "EXECUTE AS USER". More details are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354.aspx).

Also 'msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail' is not supported in SQL Azure, however here is a [blog which has the solution](http://vpolizzi.wordpress.com/2010/09/11/database-mail-on-sql-azure/) for you. There could be other solutions as well but you sure can consider the top one to use.

Answer (score 0):

We just hit this same issue / thanks to everyone who's replied so far for pointing us in the right direction.
I've knocked up a quick fix, replacing the `sp_helpuser` function with a script to fetch all members of a given role.  Note: I've not recreated `sp_hepuser` itself, as that could be called from other scopes; but have amended `aspnet_Setup_RemoveAllRoleMembers` to query the underlying tables directly instead of calling `sp_helpuser`.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[aspnet_Setup_RemoveAllRoleMembers]
    @name   sysname
    AS
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #aspnet_RoleMembers
    (
        Group_name      sysname,
        Group_id        smallint,
        Users_in_group  sysname,
        User_id         smallint
    )

    INSERT INTO #aspnet_RoleMembers (Group_name, Group_id, Users_in_group, User_id)
    --begin code to replace sp_helpuser
    select roles.name Role_name
    , roles.principal_id Role_id
    , members.name Users_in_role
    , members.principal_id Userid
    from sys.database_principals roles
    inner join sys.database_role_members link on link.role_principal_id = roles.principal_id
    inner join sys.database_principals members on members.principal_id = link.member_principal_id
    where roles.type = 'R'
    and roles.name = @name
    --end code to replace sp_helpuser

    DECLARE @user_id smallint
    DECLARE @cmd nvarchar(500)
    DECLARE c1 cursor FORWARD_ONLY FOR
        SELECT User_id FROM #aspnet_RoleMembers
    OPEN c1
        FETCH c1 INTO @user_id
        WHILE (@@fetch_status = 0)
        BEGIN
            SET @cmd = 'EXEC sp_droprolemember ' + '''' + @name + ''', ''' + USER_NAME(@user_id) + ''''
            EXEC (@cmd)
            FETCH c1 INTO @user_id
        END
    CLOSE c1
    DEALLOCATE c1
END
GO
```

We've not yet tested this solution; so use at your own risk... Hope it helps though...