# SQL Azure Automated Tasks - Step-by-Step guide?

Tags: c#, sql-server, scheduled-tasks, azure-sql-database

I have migrated a database to SQL Azure but need to have a scheduled task run every evening. I always see references to "roles" or other methods that can be used to simulate an automated tasks function but I have yet to see a step-by-step guide for this. Does a guide exist for this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can read it here:

[part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/07/30/10044271.aspx)

[part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/08/02/10045012.aspx)

[part 3](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/08/03/10045404.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

And then you can take the [SQL Azure Agent](http://sqlazureagent.codeplex.com/), which was built on top of the mentioned articles ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is a discussion about this topic under this post that might be helpful.

[Scheduled Tasks with Sql Azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6057851/scheduled-tasks-with-sql-azure)

Answer (score 0):

Other than creating Worker Roles, you can also use the scheduler..

http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/build-your-own-sql-server-agent-for-windows-azure-sql-database-with-the-scheduler/