# Scheduled Task on SQL Azure

Tags: sql, azure, task, azure-sql-database, schedule

I actually search for a system to do a task every day at a precise time. This task is to delete some entries in the database.
I have a Web Role and a Sql Azure database.
I found some tutorial but nothing very effective and simple.
Can somebody help me ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scheduled Tasks with Sql Azure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6057851/scheduled-tasks-with-sql-azure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a lok at this SO post [Scheduled Tasks with Sql Azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6057851/scheduled-tasks-with-sql-azure).

As of now there is no equivalent of SQL job in SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to using a service to do this scheduling of tasks, an alternate solution to purchasing your own worker role is to use [Cotega](http://www.cotega.com) which supports this functionality.  For example, you can [schedule it to launch stored procedure](http://cotega.com/docs/sql_azure_scheduled_job) on regular intervals.

Full disclosure, I work on this service.