# Database and hosting with ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure, hosting

I started to work on an ASP.NET MVC5 application but I still not decided where I will host everything and what type of database I will use. The first option I thought was shared or vps hosting (like Godaddy) that includes traditionnal MSSQL and MySQL. The second option is Azure Websites which seems more scalable and adapted. However, on the short term, I fear this option is more expansive.

First question : Is there any other option I didn't see ?

Second question : SQL Azure and SQL Server are they exactly the same thing ? Can I still use the Entity Framework the same way ?

Third question : Do you have any suggestions... pros and cons ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I fear this option is more expansive.

It is not exactly right. AzureWebsites offer in 3 modes - [Free/Shared/Standard](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-scale/). Based on the mode you run, there will be [pricing](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/web-sites/#web-sites). If your application got limited visitors you can run on Free mode, which is least expensive.

> First question : Is there any other option I didn't see ?

Not that I can think of. Your options are - OnPremises, Cloud, Shared Hosting Providers. You are exploring Cloud and Shared hosting providers.

> Second question : SQL Azure and SQL Server are they exactly the same
>   thing ?

SQL Azure is not exactly the same SQL Server. It got its own limitations -

- Transact SQL Limitations - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee336253.aspx
- Other Guidelines and Limitations - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394102.aspx
- [This thread showed lot of limitations and associated resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235164/what-is-the-difference-between-sql-azure-and-sql-server-2008)

> Can I still use the Entity Framework the same way ?

SQL Azure got EF Compatibility - http://www.windowsazure.com/EN-US/develop/net/how-to-guides/sql-database/

Comment: The free mode doesn't have custom domain name, so I have to use the shared version. The price is $10 per month... but soon it will be $15. Cheap.. but not cheaper than Godaddy for example.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Azure has some Execution Models:

-Web Sites
-Cloud Services
-Virtual Machines

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/choose-web-site-cloud-service-vm/

To use a database you should go with Virtual Machines and install it in there. There's a image of virtual machine that already has Sql server and you don't need to apply your own license, it's in the price you'll pay.

You can also use some features of Windows Azure Storage, such as Table Services or SQL Database (Sql Server for Azure with limitations @ramiramilu said)

Answer (score 0):

if you're just looking at it in terms of the cost of hosting your site, then you may find that traditional hosting may be cheaper.

Windows Azure Websites though provides more than just hosting. You get staging slot, source control integration, monitoring and alerts, redundancy, auto-scaling, etc...